# Not posting to SQLite Database

Tags: php, sqlite

How can i get my form to submit to my SQLite database, i think i need to add an INSERT INTO statement somewhere. I'm stupid when it comes to PHP, could someone explain why its not working and help me get it to work?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Input</title>
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('sqlite:mydb.sqlite3');
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $dbh->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
             name VARCHAR(30),
             gender VARCHAR(30),
             age INTEGER)"
             );

    $data = array(
            array('name' => 'Daniel', 'gender' => 'Male', 'age' => '21')
            );

    $insert = "INSERT INTO test (name, gender, age)
           VALUES (:name, :gender, :age)";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($insert);


foreach ($data as $m) {
    $name = $m['name'];
    $gender = $m['gender'];
    $age = $m['age'];
    $stmt->bindParam('name', $name);
    $stmt->bindParam('gender', $gender);
    $stmt->bindParam('age', $age);

    $stmt->execute();

}
    $result = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM test');

    $dbh = null;

}
    catch(PDOException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();
}       

?> 

<div id="wrapper">

   <div class="banner1">
        <h2>Input</h2>
   </div>

<form id="form" method="post">
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name[0]"/> <br>
    Gender:<br>
    <input type="text" name="gender[0]"/> <br>
    Age:<br>
    <input type="number" name="age[0]" min="1" max="99"/> <br>

    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Input">
    </form>

</div>

<div id="results">

    <div class="banner2">
            <h2>Results</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="data">
        <?php
            unset($_POST['submit']);
            $data=$_POST;

            foreach ($result as $row) {
            echo $row['name']  . " ";
            echo $row['gender'] . " " ;
            echo $row['age']  . "<br>" . " ";
            }

        ?> 
    </div>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is a screenshot so you can grasp an idea of the form and how i'd like it to work. The results section is just generated from the array so i can see what is being inputted, but i'd like the input form to send data to the SQLite database that i have created/connected to above. Thank you.
[image: Screenshot of Form:]

Comment: Use `$_POST` to get input from the form, and use that when inserting into the database.